# import all dependencies from one Gradle module to another

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have two modules in my build, an Android app and a Java library. (Side story, the Java library is to run jvm tests against classes in the Android app. Since it needs the Gradle Java plugin and that is incompatible with the Gradle Android plugin, I had to split them out.)

In the java module I want to import all the dependencies of the other module automatically, so as to avoid having to keep them in sync.

How can you configure one module's `compileTest` dependencies to match another modules `compile` dependencies?

(Alternative suggestions for using both plugins welcome.)

Comment: Don't you get the dependencies from module1 if you just write `dependencies { testCompile project(':module1') }` in the `build.gradle` file in module2?

Comment: Oh, that does work. I was initially confused because when I tried that, it was missing a lot of Android dependencies. But it looks like those dependencies aren't listed as dependencies since the Android project was applying the Android plugin, thus I had to add that in manually in the second module. But the listed dependencies do get imported. If you'll add that as the answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will get the `compile` dependencies of module1 as `testCompile` dependencies in module2 if you write:

```
dependencies { 
    testCompile project(':module1') 
}
```

in the `build.gradle` file of module2. As you stated in the comments yourself, you won't get dependencies from the android plugin applied in module1 if it is not applied in module2.

**EDIT:** Added the following description of how to define dependencies in a separate script.

As mentioned in the comments, an alternative is to add properties in a separate script that defines every 3rd party dependency. I tend to do this on every multi-project build that I'm involved in. Actually, since I'm so used to the existence of a `dependencies.gradle` file, I actually do this on single-project builds as well.

The idea is simple enough:

- add a separate script with properties defining your 3rd party dependencies
- apply this script in every module
- use the properties instead of duplicated hard-coding everywhere

That way you have all your dependencies defined in one place, the readability of the dependency definitions are increased and your modules will never get "out of sync" with each other (e.g. two modules depending on different versions of the same library). An added bonus is that you can combine several dependencies that belongs together in one single property.

**Example:**

Say we have 2 modules as described in the question. Module 1 uses some 3rd party libraries. Module 2 is supposed to test module 1 and needs every library defined in module 1 in addition to some of its own.

**`dependencies.gradle`**

```
ext {
    JAVAX_MAIL = 'javax.mail:mail:1.4.5'
    JODA_TIME = 'joda-time:joda-time:2.1'
    LOG4J = 'log4j:log4j:1.2.16'
    SPOCK = [
            'org.spockframework:spock-core:0.7-groovy-2.0',
            'org.objenesis:objenesis:1.2',
            'cglib:cglib-nodep:2.2.2'
    ]

    // Note: I don't usually combine dep's like this, it's just for illustration.
    //       I prefer to spell them out to make it more explicit.
    MODULE_1_DEPS = [ JAVAX_MAIL, LOG4J ]
}
```

**`module1/build.gradle`**

```
apply from: "$rootDir/dependencies.gradle"

dependencies {
    compile MODULE_1_DEPS
}
```

**`module2/build.gradle`**

```
apply from: "$rootDir/dependencies.gradle"

dependencies {
    compile JODA_TIME, LOG4J
    testCompile MODULE_1_DEPS, SPOCK
}
```

Note: If you "combine" properties into lists of lists, you *might* have to flatten the list. I.e. something like: `MY_DEP = [ DEP1, DEP2 ].flatten()`. *Perhaps* gradle does it for you, I honestly don't know -- I haven't tested it.

Also note: The examples here are just illustrations on how to achieve what you want, they are not in any way complete.

Comment: Interestingly enough, it's pulling in the stated dependencies but not the transitive ones, even though the main module compiles fine with the transitive dependencies.

Comment: That was surprising - and it might also become a problem. In multi-project builds I tend to create a `dependencies.gradle` file with the dependencies defined as properties. That way, I get more readable dependency definitions and keep all dependency definitions in one place. The properties can even contain multiple dependencies (as lists), so you can combine all wanted dependencies into one, if that makes sense -- which I guess it does in your case. I can edit my answer to include an example of this if you'd like.

Comment: I'd appreciate that, it sounds like that'd be nice from a maintenance perspective.